# No Cloud Services when signing into Microsoft Azure Publish

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, active-directory, azure-management

When signing into Microsoft Azure Publish in Visual Studio 2013 (right click Cloud Project -> "Publish..."), none of my cloud services are appearing.

This has previously always been working for me.

Signing in using my Windows Live account (I am a "co-administrator"):

[image]

When opening the publish window, I get this popup asking me to create a new service!

[image]

Because as you can see, I now have no services:

[image]

I have no idea what has happened.  Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**  I tried signing in with the Administrator credentials - same problem!

Comment: Make sure you have latest Azure SDK installed. If so could this be certificate expiry? Perhaps try removing the subscription and downloading and importing the publish settings file again.

Comment: @SimonW: I am not using certificates, only sign in.

Comment: Some services such as Azure SQL DB require you to use certificate-based authentication. Try importing a publish settings file to populate the certificates portion of the dialogs you are showing above.